# spark-streaming batch interval for kafka topic reprocessing

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

**Current setting**: a Spark Streaming job processes a Kafka topic of timeseries data. About every second new data comes in of different sensors. Also, the batch interval is 1 Second. By means of `updateStateByKey()` stateful data is computed as a new stream. As soon as this stateful data crosses a treshold, an event is generated on a Kafka topic. When the value later drops below the treshhold, again an event is fired that topic.

So far, so good.

**Problem**: when applying a new algorithm on the data by reconsuming the Kafka topic, I would like this to go fast. But this means that every batch contains (hundreds of) thousands messages. Moving these in 1 batch to `updateStateByKey()` results in 1 computed value for that key on the resulting stream.

Of course that's unacceptable as loads of data points are reduced to a single one. Alarm events that will be generated on a real-time stream will not be on the recomputed stream. So comparing algorithms this way is totally useless.

**Question**: How can I avoid this? Preferably not switching frameworks. It seems to me I'm looking for a true streaming (1 event a a time) framework. On the other hand Spark streaming is new to me, so I'm definitely missing a lot there.

Comment: Your question is too abstract!!! some code and detail might help.

Answer (score 0):

In spark 1.6, a new API `mapWithState` for interacting with state has been introduced. I believe that will solve your problem.

Have a look at it [here](https://databricks.com/blog/2016/02/01/faster-stateful-stream-processing-in-apache-spark-streaming.html).